# Why is readline not reading every line

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I'm trying to find (with Regex) in a big text file, the first line where there is a 'False' instead of a 'True'. There are multiple lines where that is the case.

Text File example:

```
test, test, test, True,
test, test, test, True,
test, test, test, False, (i want this line)
test, test, test, False,
test, test, test, True,
test, test, test, True,
test, test, test, False,(and that) 
test, test, test, False,
test, test, test, True,
test, test, test, True,
```

I'm reading the file line by line. Always when the line read matches the 'True' Regex it reads the next line and tries if the next line matches the 'False' Regex. If so (for now) it should print me the line.

```
try {
    BufferedReader br = 
    new BufferedReader(new FileReader(C:\\Directory\\test.txt)
    String lineRead;
    while ((lineRead = br.readLine()) != null) {
          if(lineRead.matches( ".*True.*")){
             if((lineRead = br.readLine()) != null){
                if((lineRead.matches( ".*False.*"))){
                   System.out.println(lineRead);
                }
             }
           }
    }
}
```

It gives me most of the lines but not all of them. The lines are several thousand lines apart. The 'False' lines are always several hundreds that follow up. So there shouldn't be a problem with 'overjumping' one.

Comment: Hi! When you were asking your question, there was a **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful info in it. There was also a toolbar full of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button giving formatting help. *And* a preview area showing what your post would look like when posted, located between the text area and the Post Your Question button (so that you'd have to scroll past it to find the button, to encourage you to look at it). Making your post clear, and demonstrating that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers.

Comment: I've fixed it for you this time, it may be worth looking at the edit to see how I did it. Happy coding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question's formatting is an absolute mess, but this is all you should really need here:

```
boolean flag = false;
while ((lineRead = br.readLine()) != null) {
    if (lineRead.matches(".*\\bTrue\\b.*")) {
        flag = true;
    }
    else if (lineRead.matches(".*\\bFalse\\b.*")) {
        if (flag) {
            System.out.println(lineRead);
            flag = false;
        }
    }
}
```

The boolean `flag` keeps track of the state of the previous line.  We only print a line containing false if it be the first false line after a previous true line.  And, after parsing a false line, we set the flag to false, to prevent the second false line onwards from being printed.

Comment: There are lines with `False` that the OP doesn't want. Perhaps: `boolean lastMatched = false;
while ((lineRead = br.readLine()) != null) {
    boolean thisMatches = lineRead.matches(".*\\bFalse\\b.*");
    if (thisMatches && !lastMatched) {
        System.out.println(lineRead);
    }
    lastMatched = thisMatches;
}`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I missed that.  I have updated my answer to handle this case.

Comment: Yes I tried editing my Question but you were faster. Sorry for that and thank you for the edit. Thank you for your answere. It is now working. How come it works with a internal `while` but it doesn't with a `if`? Do you perhaps know the answere?

Comment: It already worked with a `while` loop. I added it in place for the second `if` and made a `break;` after the `System.out.println` so that I only get the first one. Does any of you might know why it is working with a `while` loop (and a `break` as soon as the first one is printed) but it doesn't work with the `if`?

Comment: @Snakeeye I'm not sure what you mean, but I can say that your current logic is off, because you are nesting calls to `readLine()`, also also nesting the checks for true and false.  I recommend just sticking with the pattern of reading one line at a time, and then deciding whether or not to print it.

Answer (score 0):

Another simpler and less verbose solution could be the following:

```
private static void findFalse() {
    try(var stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(PATH))) {
        stream.filter(PATTERN.asPredicate())
            .forEach(System.out::println);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("An error has occurred:: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

First start by defining a `Pattern` like so:

`private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile(".*\\bFalse\\b.*");`

Then simply open up a stream of the file's line, filter using the pattern you have defined and output each matching line to the standard output.

This way you'll avoid setting flags as well as handing the whole reading process manually.

Answer (score 0):

Tracing through your original code, with the example that you give, I see.
line 5: reads input line 1
line 6: passes, so reads input line 2
line 7: fails
line 5: reads input line 3
line 6: fails
line 5: reads line 4
...
Hence the first set of 'False' lines will not show up, similarly any set of false lines separated by 2 'True' lines.